# Get specific string from Attribute

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-ide

I recorded a script inside Selenium IDE Chrome Add-on.

I got a variable name with value `"John Doe (johndoe@abc.com)"` stored by Store Value command.

I know execute script command can help somehow. I tried some javascript but didn't work.

I can retrieve the name + address by using `${name}` in next command but I just want the name i.e only "John Doe" from the string.

Comment: Please share the code you've tried so far and where you are having trouble.

Comment: I was using Chrome Addon

Comment: The answer below solved my problem.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You should use `execute script`command to create new variable. Here it is:

```
execute script | tmp = ${name}; return tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf('(') + 1, tmp.indexOf(')')); | address
execute script | tmp = ${name}; return tmp.substring(0, tmp.indexOf(' (')); | name
```

Comment: Thanks, I just changed it to match the American date format, it works.